# What does the colon inside the parameter mean?

Tags: python

What does the colon on words_pron_dict:str mean? I am getting syntax error on python 2.7. Is it python 3? How can i use it?

```
class TextToSpeech:
    CHUNK = 1024

    def __init__(self, words_pron_dict:str = 'cmudict-0.7b.txt'):
        self._l = {}
        self._load_words(words_pron_dict)
```

Comment: just remove `:str` and it will work in python 2 (this is a new python 3.5 feature to check type)

Answer (score 28):

It's a type annotation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

You should be able to just remove it.