# from pandas_schema import Column, Schema Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm running `python 2.7` and trying to get program working with `pandas`.  The following error message is received when importing Column.  Looks like it might be an issue with the :-

```
def __init__(self, name: str, validations: typing.Iterable['validation._BaseValidation'] = [], allow_empty=False):
```

Error Message:

> File
>   "/Users/coxda/faDataValidation27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_schema/column.py",
>   line 8
>       def **init**(self, name: str, validations: typing.Iterable['validation._BaseValidation'] = [],
>   allow_empty=False):
>                              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is because the package uses Python 3.5's type annotation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

The package documentation does not specifically mention Python 3 is required, but the syntax it uses suggests Python 3.5+ is required, or, since the package is in pure python, you could edit the `column.py` source and should be able to remove those type annotations and then successfully import the classes.

Reference: [What is the colon inside the parameter mean in python? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648300/what-is-the-colon-inside-the-parameter-mean-in-python)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes it is working when I run with Python 3.6.5.  Looks like a documentation error since it doesn't work on 2.7