# What is the purpose of a colon within the parameters of a definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was given python 3.x code but my python 2.7 interpreter won't interpret it due to the colons in the function definition.

The code I run:

```py
def __init__(self, api_key: str, base_url: Tuple[str, None] = None):
```

And the error I get:

```
File "C:\Users\3791108\Downloads\CloudClient.py", line 191
        def __init__(self, api_key: str, base_url: Tuple[str, None] = None):

                                  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected token ':'
```

Comment: Wouldn't say it's a duplicate. This question asks `what`, the question in the link asks `why`...

Comment: Here's a question that asks `what`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648300/what-does-the-colon-inside-the-parameter-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colons are type declarations.

Python 3 now has optional [type support.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)  The function definition is saying that `api_key` should be a string, and that `base_url` should be a tuple where the first element is a string and the second a NoneType.

I think the real question is why are you trying to run python 3.X code in a 2.7 interpreter?  This is a different language with no guarantee of compatibility as you have found.

Comment: I was given an api client file for python. The application that will be the client uses ironpython 2.7 as an intepreter. Thus, I am tweaking the 3.x python file to run through an ironpython 2.7 intepreter. Thanks for your help