# Is this another way of passing arguments to functions in Python+pytest?

Tags: python, function, syntax, automation, pytest

I am trying to understand a python program and its using pytest framework to write tests. In the definition of functions the arguments are passed in the following way:

`def get_name(a: ABC, b:DEF) -> str`

where ABC and DEF are classes, Can anyone help me to understand what is happening here and why are we using a:ABC, couldn't I just write a = ABC?
I have tried finding this way of passing arguments but no luck.

Comment: It's typing as defined here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the colon inside the parameter mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648300/what-does-the-colon-inside-the-parameter-mean)